# create a JSON object from PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL version 9.6. My table is defined like this:

```
 CREATE TABLE item_properties
(
    id serial NOT NULL,
    item_id integer,
    property_name character varying(255),
    property_value character varying(255),
    CONSTRAINT item_properties_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
);


INSERT INTO item_properties(item_id, property_name, property_value)
VALUES('1', 'widget', 'val1');
INSERT INTO item_properties(item_id, property_name, property_value)
VALUES('1', 'cog', '0124');
INSERT INTO item_properties(item_id, property_name, property_value)
VALUES('1', 'screw', 'long');
INSERT INTO item_properties(item_id, property_name, property_value)
VALUES('1', 'foo', '000');
```

I would like to get a JSON object from this table content which will look like this:

```
{
  "widget": "val1",
  "cog": "0124",
  "screw": "long",
  "foo": "000"
}
```

I would like to accomplish this by a PostgreSQL query.

Comment: `select json_object_agg(property_name, property_value) from item_properties
group by item_id`

Comment: Also in table creation, here `... PRIMARY KEY (id),` no need comma